# Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ipv6, appstore-approval

it might sound stupid but i have a problem: iTunes Connect rejected my app, claiming "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.". and they want me to: "Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.".
Now, I understand that since 6/16 each app should supports IPv6. Because an application is just a software, i understand that they mean that each URL that I enter from my app should be accessible through IPv6. The weird part is that when i'm trying to reach sites which only available at IPv6 (like http://test-ipv6.com/, http://ds.testmyipv6.com/) i can't reach them, not from Android device, iOs devices, or from any mac. It's hard to believe that different ISP-s doesn't provide IPv6 support.

What am i missing here ? 
Did any of you had that problem ?
Anything similar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't reproduce (IPv6?) connection issue that App Store review team is having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642892/cant-reproduce-ipv6-connection-issue-that-app-store-review-team-is-having)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean that servers need to be accessible through IPv6 (although it is highly recommended), it means that your application shouldn't care whether the server is IPv4 or IPv6. Some networks use NAT64 and DNS64 and will give your application IPv6 addresses even for servers that are only reachable over IPv4.

Apple's requirement is that your application must work in such situations.

This has been asked many times. Please look at previous answers. Here are some references:

- [Is Apple iOS defaulting to IPv6-only, on an app-by-app basis, in the real world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974044/is-apple-ios-defaulting-to-ipv6-only-on-an-app-by-app-basis-in-the-real-world)
- [Can't reproduce (IPv6?) connection issue that App Store review team is having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642892/cant-reproduce-ipv6-connection-issue-that-app-store-review-team-is-having)